# Databinding HtmlEncode ":" is an error?

Tags: .net, webforms

My code is working locally. However when I deploy to the production web server I receive the following error for Line 82:

**Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'**

```
Line 80: <ItemTemplate>
Line 81:   <tr>
Line 82:     <td><span class="label label-info"><%#: Item.QuestionNumber %></span></td>
```

The remote web server is reporting the following version information:

**Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1008**

Now as far as I know **<%#:** was introduced with .NET 4. So why am I getting this error?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<%:` syntax was introduced in ASP.NET 4 which allows you to HTML encode content before it's rendered, however, this doesn't work with data binding expressions.

Support for HTML encoded data bound expressions (i.e. `<%#:` syntax) was added in ASP.NET 4.5. See the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097391).